# Why Keywords are producing errors though respective assemblies are included already in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, .net-assembly, assembly-references

I am preparing Windows Store App with C# & xaml led by online examples.
Many times when I try to use a keyword like: 
"File" in 
`System.IO.File.WriteAllLines()`
or
"Frame" in 
`this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MyPage));`

I took care of adding appropriate "using required_assembly"
I get error like:

> The type or namespace name 'File' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The steps I took to try resolving errors were:

1. I did Rebuild & Clean Build after removing & then re-adding using statements.
2. I Unload & then Reload the project from solution explorer.
3. Browsed the Object-Browser & yes the assemblies were there.
4. Checked the "References" in the Solution Explorer, now this is where the `System.IO` was not present & when I tried to manually add the reference it said that "All of the Framework assemblies are already referenced".

Why is Visual Studio producing these errors?

Comment: Do you have a different example or is that the main one? Because so far as I'm aware, `System.IO.File` isn't available for Windows Store apps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out this & yes you are completely right about the System.IO.File not present for Windows Store Apps.

Comment: Also, you seem to have been lucky and someone edited your question - the right way to avoid downvotes is to *write a good question* - show what you've done (be *specific*), what solutions you've already rejected (include links, where possible). Vague things like "I've searched the entire internet and nothing helped" doesn't help *us* to know what solutions you've actually found and attempted.